# How can i do a menu chooser in android

Tags: android, menu

I want to do a menu where u can choose the audio apps that are installed in your phone (like Youtube, Music, Skype...) so I don´t know the exactly name of this type of menu (if this have a special name).

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are searching for: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (intent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Replace `com.package.address` with the package name of the application you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you would to send file to another app based on type of this file.

This code allows to send audio file to selected app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose app"));
```

[More info](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)